# I can't figure out the mysql alter column syntax

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to change the datatype of a column in MYSQL. Curiously, absolutely every solution that i can find in internet including stackoverflow, leads me to a syntax problem. I don't know much about sql, I just solve my things stitching other's solutions, but this time, even the standard solutions show syntax errors in https://sql.treasuredata.com/ and at my own context.

```
ALTER TABLE `flashes_finnish`
ALTER COLUMN `learnt` INTEGER
```

and...

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'my column';
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To change column a from INTEGER to TINYINT NOT NULL (leaving the name the same), and to change column b from CHAR(10) to CHAR(20) as well as renaming it from b to c:

```
ALTER TABLE t2 MODIFY a TINYINT NOT NULL, CHANGE b c CHAR(20);
```

You can refer [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table-examples.html) for more examples. If you are still having errors please do post more about the error message and your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your second statement appears to be syntactically valid for MySQL, but not for ApacheHive.

The first statement, the keyword `ALTER` before `COLUMN` should be replaced with the keyword `MODIFY`, e.g.

```
  ALTER TABLE `flashes_finnish` MODIFY COLUMN `learnt` INTEGER
                                ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Wow! I was completely unaware of Mysql having different syntax versions. I will look it up more soon. Thanks!

Comment: ApacheHive syntax is *not* the same thing as MySQL syntax.  [**MySQL Reference Manual** SQL Statement Syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax.html).